# Excel filter Pivot (External Data source) based on rows with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following issue: I have an external Database connected to my file and its displayed as a pivot. Now I got a tutorial on how to do this from the web and for normal pivot tables it works, however not for the one connected to the external data source. Find attached the code:

```
Sub FilterMultipleRowItems()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  Dim vArray As Variant
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim pvFld As PivotField
  Set pvFld = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("OMSCube").PivotFields( _
        "[dim_Article_Active].[ArticleNumber].[ArticleNumber]")
  vArray = Worksheets("Input").Range("AC4:AC10")
  pvFld.ClearAllFilters

  With pvFld
    For i = 1 To pvFld.PivotItems.Count
      j = 1
       Do While j <= UBound(vArray, 1) - LBound(vArray, 1) + 1
         If pvFld.PivotItems(i).Name = vArray(j, 1) Then
           pvFld.PivotItems(pvFld.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = True
           Exit Do
        Else
          pvFld.PivotItems(pvFld.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
        End If
        j = j + 1
      Loop
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

The code always break in this line:

```
Else
          pvFld.PivotItems(pvFld.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
```

with the error message:

[image: Error Message]

Debug Results:

[image: Debug Results]

First one to help me solve this receives a virtual cookie, because this feature decides over whether the product could work or not.

Thanks and have a good day

I don't know whats the issue here, but I have two guesses:

- When I try to filter this field manually, I get the message: "Not all items shown". Maybe this makes the code break at some point.
- The naming of my fields is wrong. Due to the connection of the external Datasource the naming of the fields is not similar to the tutorial on the web and maybe I messed something up when renaming. I had to find out the fields by my self by manually filtering the pivot and checking the macro generated code.

The goal of the excercise is to autmatically filter a Pivot Table, but I run into issues because in my example the pivot is an external Data source.